# defer is not working on jquery.min.js in laravel 6 blade

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, asynchronous, deferred

```
<script src="{{ asset('/assets/js/jquery.min.js') }}" ></script>
```

I need to add defer like

```
<script src="{{ asset('/assets/js/jquery.min.js') }}" defer></script>
```

when I add defer the jquery is not working on my site. I'm using laravel 6 version.

anyone can help me what is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Try with below codes,

```
// check your js file's path is public/assets/js/jquery.min.js 
1. <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/jquery.min.js') }}" defer></script>

// if your js file's path is public/js/jquery.min.js
2. <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}" defer></script>
```